# Using ServiceStack Profiler to profile SQL but failed

Tags: c#, sqlite, mvc-mini-profiler, ormlite-servicestack

I am using another file than global.asax for ServiceStack configuration like below:

```
   public class ApiAppHost : AppHostBase
    {
     public ApiAppHost() : base("OpenTaskApi", typeof(MyService).Assembly) { }
     public override void Configure(Container container)
     {
           container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
               new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
                   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString,
                    false,
                    ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqliteDialect.Provider) { 
                    ConnectionFilter = x=> 
                            new ProfiledDbConnection(x,Profiler.Current)
                }
            );
    }
}
```

in global.asax I have

```
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       new ApiAppHost().Init();
   }
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Profiler.Start();
   }
   protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Profiler.Stop();
   }
```

I got profiler only works on requests without profiling sql as in picutrue below
[image]

Please note: I am using asp.net project not asp.net mvc as container of my services. 
How I can fix this code to profile SQL?

Comment: Profiler doesn't work at all on requests that profile sql? Or it still works, and just doesn't show the sql in the profiler?